# Codeigniter search not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am just trying to do the basic search in the codeigniter.

controller

```
$brand = $this->uri->segment(2);
$brand = utf8_decode(urldecode($brand));
$search['type'] = 5;
$search['title'] = $brand;
$this->data['deal_brand'] = $this->manage_m->search($search);
print_r($this->data['deal_brand']);
```

Model

```
function search($search)
{
        $query = $this->db->get_where('manage', $search);
        return $query->first_row();
}
```

the search works for the following

```
www.mydomain.com/deal/audi
```

and not works for

```
www.mydomain.com/deal/citroën
```

When i get the last query it prints

```
SELECT * FROM (`manage`) WHERE `type` = 5 AND `title` = 'citroën'
```

query seems correct but not working. But it works when i copy this and run in the mysql server or like static query like below

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (`manage`) WHERE `type` = 5 AND `title` = 'citroën'");
print_r($query->result());
```

Thanks to all

Comment: sounds like an encoding issue, are you using UTF-8 all around?(mysql?) 
is the charset set to UTF in codeigniter? 

in application/config, what is the $config['charset']  setting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'; is set in the config

Comment: and these are in the database.php 
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

Comment: Okay, what does "not working" mean? do you get an error?

Comment: I got empty result when the parameter is  citroën

Comment: But i got the result when i run the sql $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (`manage`) WHERE `type` = 5 AND `title` = 'citroën'");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this : utf8_decode

From the docs : This function decodes data, assumed to be UTF-8 encoded, to ISO-8859-1.

This is clearly not what you want to do, Your entire software is in UTF-8, no reason to convert it to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: you want me to use only urldecode? if use only that the decode text is wrong

Comment: citroÃ«n - this is the string i got if i only use the  urldecode

Comment: That's because your browser is not in UTF, in chrome, go to settings (3 vertical lines) -> more tools -> encoding, make sure it's UTF-8

Comment: I can't understand. My issue with the sql query and decoding not with the browser

Comment: Your issue is mixed. You were manipulating a string, thus destroying it's content, which resulted in an empty result. We fixed that, you tried to echo out what you get, And you saw a wrong output, That output comes from the browser trying to encode the string differently